# No network after apt upgrade: "Error: Device for nexthop is not up", debian 11

Tags: linux, networking

After doing an apt upgrade recently, upon reboot I have no network. The kernel was updated, rebooting with the old kernel from grub menu gives the same result. iproute2 was also upgraded, I suspect this may be the culprit, but I don't know how to fix it.

Output of journalctl -xeu networking.service:

```
Apr 09:11:51 debian systemd[1]: Starting Raise network interfaces...  
░░ Subject: A start job for unit networking.service has begun execution  
░░ Defined-By: systemd  
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support  
░░   
░░ A start job for unit networking.service has begun execution.  
░░   
░░ The job identifier is 121.  
Apr 23 09:11:51 debian ifup[914]: Error: Device for nexthop is not up.  
Apr 23 09:11:51 debian ifup[904]: run-parts: /etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-autoipd exited  with return code 2  
Apr 23 09:11:51 debian ifup[834]: ifup: failed to bring up enp3s0  
Apr 23 09:11:51 debian systemd[1]: networking.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE  
░░ Subject: Unit process exited  
░░ Defined-By: systemd  
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support  
░░   
░░ An ExecStart= process belonging to unit networking.service has exited.  
░░   
░░ The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1.  
Apr 23 09:11:51 debian systemd[1]: networking.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.  
░░ Subject: Unit failed  
░░ Defined-By: systemd  
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support  
░░   
░░ The unit networking.service has entered the 'failed' state with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 23 09:11:51 debian systemd[1]: Failed to start Raise network interfaces.  
░░ Subject: A start job for unit networking.service has failed  
░░ Defined-By: systemd  
░░ Support: https://www.debian.org/support  
░░   
░░ A start job for unit networking.service has finished with a failure.  
░░   
░░ The job identifier is 121 and the job result is failed.
```

Contents of /etc/networking/interfaces (working before upgrade):

```
#The loopback network interface  
auto lo  
iface lo inet loopback  

#The primary network interface  
auto enp3s0  
iface enp3s0 inet static  
    address 10.0.0.9  
    netmask 255.255.255.0  
    gateway 10.0.0.2
```

Comment: Please, try to collect more info. What was the previous Debian version; output of `lspci -nnk` (only of the network device), `dmesg` (lines concerning network), `ip a` (are there any other network interfaces than `lo`?), look for running system helpers like `NetworkManager`, do you work just with CLI (command line) or your Debian starts Xwindows GUI? Some information can be find in `/var/log/syslog`.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out I had a custom script called `ip` in `/usr/local/bin` that caused a problem after I did the upgrade.

It's been in there for months and never caused a problem, I'm guessing the call to it was using a full path before, but is not now.

Anyway, after I removed this custom `ip` script from `/usr/local/bin` and rebooted everything is working now.